# Styling Atom Text Editor

Tags: css, atom-editor

So i've opened up my `Atom` stylesheets which is named : `styles.less` and made some changes so my stylesheet now looks like :

```
tree-view {
  background-color: #101;
}

// style the background and foreground colors on the atom-text-editor-element itself
atom-text-editor {
  color: white;
  background-color: #101;
}

// To style other content in the text editor's shadow DOM, use the ::shadow expression
atom-text-editor::shadow .cursor {
  border-color: red;
}
```

I'm trying to change the colour of the panels at the top and maybe a few other things. Is there anyway I can find out the `class`/`ID` names for elements in Atom for me to style?

Comment: `View - Developer - Toggle Dev Tools`

Comment: You can use the inspector for this. You can find those through the menu `View > Developer > Toggle Developer Tools` (OSX, other platforms should be similar)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! If one of you guys want to submit an answer i'll accept it. This worked, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 9):

One way is to open atom's developer tools.

On OSX -> `View - Developer - Toggle Developer Tools`

Where you can inspect the elements and find what you need.

Also see [How to make Developer Tools appear?](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-make-developer-tools-appear/16232)

Answer (score 2):

You can view the StyleGuide from the menu > Packages > StyleGuide > show

or just click , Ctrl(Command) + Shift + G ,
there you will find all the class/ID names.

Comment: It seems this only works when you are doing changes to a UI Syntax Theme, not for the editor part but I might be mistaken...